# Anyone have experience with AppScale?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, appscale

I just found this project which provides a way of running Google App Engine projects on your own server cluster.

http://code.google.com/p/appscale/

It looks really interesting, has anyone had any experience using it?

Comment: FYI, they're now on github: https://github.com/AppScale/appscale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find users of it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/appscale_community).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we are using Appscale. 
In fact you can try it by downloading the latest images here:
http://www.appscale.com/community/downloads/

Or by building it on your own machine:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /root
# wget -O - http://bootstrap.appscale.com | sh
```

You can find more about this [here](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Virtualized-Cluster).